# Queueing async Task Operations?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multitasking

I have a asp.net web application, and in a form i use async process.

```
Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                foreach (ListItem item in cbListFaculties.Items)
                {
                    if (item.Selected)
                    {
                        service.FinishSyncDepartment(actionId, item.Value);
                    }
                }
            });
```

But what i want to do is, if the Task has started and user hits that page again, i want to say, that task hasn't stop yet, so you can't continue.

How can i resolve this issue? Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: By using some shared resource like static variable/session variable to sync multiple page requests?

Comment: To elaborate on what sll is saying, in a session state variable or some other persistent form, set a flag saying the process has begun, then begin the process and when it's done, reset the flag. When the user comes to the page, check the flag. If it's set, warn them that the process is currently operating. At that point, you can do whatever. You can reload every few seconds until the flag gets reset, or send them to another page, etc...

Comment: Is the reference to the `Task` alive or you do a complete page reload and loose the reference to the Task? If so, then probably you need to save the reference to the Task to work with it later. To do that you can(for example) move Task declaration and startup to another class that is not dependent on your page. For example use some static class so that Task will be there after page reload too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `Task` object(instead of running it at once) and use [`IsCompleted` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.iscompleted.aspx) to check if it was completed. Or you can use some thread safe object (static field) to flag that task is busy.

If you need the task to survive during page reloads - than you'll have to save reference to that `Task` object in some manner(cookie, session, static variable, viewstate, cache, database....)

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a reference to the task inside the Code Behind, so if the `Task` has not been disposed then the task has not completed.

Comment: The codebehind page reference gets destroyed as soon as the response is sent to the client. When the user for example hits refresh, a new Page instance is usually created on the server, so the Task reference is lost.

Comment: @HonzaBrestan Yes the CodeBehind is destroyed, but he could preserve the reference in the Session or ViewState.

Comment: ViewState gets serialized and sent to the client. You can hardly do that with a reference. With session it is possible, however I'd say it's a bad idea - Session can get flushed at any time, it might also require serialization as well (for example when stored in DB or on a session server)

Answer (score 0):

Do like 0x49D1 wrote, but put task object in session and don't use static fields on the web.